# Replace debian control scripts in native packer

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to override the debain control scripts generated by the sbt native packer plugin. Allas, the plugin only allows me to append to the generated scripts. Instead of appending I want/need to replace some of the scripts. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are settings for all supported control scripts you can override. For example [debianControlFile](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/debian/Keys.scala#L20) or [debianMakePreinstScript](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/debian/Keys.scala#L39).

The [DebianPlugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/debian/DebianPlugin.scala#L108) provides some defaults. If you are using an archetype you get some extras. The server archetype [overrides some tasks](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaServerApplication.scala#L109) to provide other mappings.

**UPDATE**

The behaviour works as I described. However this is for sbt-native-packager 1.0.0-RC1. This means

1. Add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-RC1")` to your `plugins.sbt`
2. Remove everything debian script stuff from your `build.sbt`
3. Add your debian scripts (like you did) in the `src/debian/DEBIAN` folder. They will override the standard ones.

So your `build.sbt` will look like this

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV

name := """play-debian-ctrl"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, JDebPackaging)

daemonUser in Linux := "sometest"
serverLoading in Debian := SystemV
maintainer in Debian := "Jan Friderici <jnfrd@outlook.com>"
packageSummary := "Some More Tests"
packageDescription := """Even much more test, or text?."""

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

Comment: I know, but the contents of the debianMakePreinstScript will be appended to the default file provided by the archetype. I want it to replace the default one. Im using play so I can't easily switch of those settings.

Comment: I will try to reproduce this with play. You can also open a bug, because this isn't the expected behaviour. If you can provide a small sample application showing this would be awesome :)

Comment: This is a "feature". The documentation states: "If you use the packageArchetype.java_server there are predefined postinst and preinst files, which start/stop the application on install/remove calls. Existing maintainer scripts will be extended not overridden." (http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/debian.html right at the bottom)

Comment: Here is an example project: The debian postinst file is appended and the override file is ignored https://github.com/fride/play-debain-ctrl

Comment: Still does not work with a multi module project using play (2.3.8) as sbt insists on using the native and not the jdeb implementation. I will check it out on a debian box.

Comment: JDeb will only work on play 2.4.x, when everything has moved to autoplugins :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way not to append to the default scripts is to remove them by adding the following to your build.sbt:

```
// disable all default control scripts
debianMakePreinstScript := None

debianMakePrermScript := None

debianMakePostinstScript := None

debianMakePostrmScript := None
```

Now you should not have any defaults and you are free to use your custom once.